# Install linux headers 3.7 on debian 8

Tags: software-installation, aptitude

I'm trying to install the amd64 radeon catalyst driver, but it needs kernel headers for 3.7

This is the output of `uname -r`:

```
3.16.0-4-amd64
```

I've already ran apt-get update, `apt-cache search linux-headers` outputs this

```
linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common - Common header files for Linux 3.16.0-4
linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64 - Header files for Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64
linux-headers-amd64 - Header files for Linux amd64 configuration (meta-package)
linux-headers-3.16.0-4-all - All header files for Linux 3.16 (meta-package)
linux-headers-3.16.0-4-all-amd64 - All header files for Linux 3.16 (meta-package)
```

It seems like I only have v3.16 on my repositories...

All the help I've found on the internet is for kali, and it won't work on my debian... please help :(

Is there any repository for debian containing linux-headers for 3.7?

If it gives any help, this is my /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8.0.0 _Jessie_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20150425-12:54]/ jessie contrib main

deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib

# jessie-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib

# firefox
deb http://packages.linuxmint.com debian import

# google chrome
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

Comment: I ran into this question / answer when I was looking for the headers package for Debian 8. The version that tracks your kernel is "linux-headers-amd64". While that might not help someone looking for 3.7 headers, it will help someone looking for the headers of their running machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Debian version which uses 3.7 (anymore?).

When you want to compile for the running kernel, you would need the headers for 3.16.

Have you seen https://wiki.debian.org/ATIProprietary?

Comment: thanks man! that's right. I just ran `apt-get install linux-headers-3.16.0.4-all` and the installation went neat! just for the record, I downloaded Radeon R6 graphics drivers from here http://www.techspot.com/downloads/drivers/essentials/amd-catalyst-linux/ . Now, the brightness buttons are working "awesomly".

Comment: Why don't you download it directly from AMD?

Comment: I didn't found it. In fact, I couldn't find "Radeon R6 graphics" on their website... I found several drivers for R*, but none of them was compatible with R6, finally, I found that driver on techspot... I'm glad it worked